# Transition Kernel and Transition matrix

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, hidden-markov-models

I know that this question might sound too vague, but what is the difference between a transition matrix and transition kernel. In my stochastic processes class we mentioned the transition matrix with its properties, but I am not aware of the transition kernel.

Also, I am working with hidden Markov models and observation kernels are mentions. What does observation kernel refer to?

Comment: A transition matrix is a transition kernel on a finite space. On a finite space, there is a matrix representation.

Comment: Yes I am working with a finite state space S={1,...,k} Do you have any reference for this statement?

Comment: @Sisyphus As the books I am looking at mention transition kernels even when working with finite state spaces.